# How to open .deb from nautilus with apturl?

Tags: nautilus, apturl

I want to open .deb-files by double-clicking with apturl - the same way as packages are installed from ubuntuusers.de with firefox. Instead, the software-center opens everytime. I can't see an entry for apturl when right-clicking .deb-files, 'open with' - just software-center or archivemanager. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Right click the .deb, click properties, and then go to the open with tab. Then click show other applications, select apt-url from the list, and then click set as default.</strike> Try opening `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and adding this line to the default associations section: `application/x-deb=AptURL.desktop;`

Comment: Let my cite my question "I can't see an entry for apturl when right-clicking .deb-files, 'open with' - just software-center or archivemanager." - see?

Comment: @Der_Techniker Let me cite my answer. Don't just click open with, click properties, then the open with tab, and click show more applications, it will list all applications on your computer, and you will be able to select apt-url.

Comment: @handuel, I'm not getting apt-url on the list. What can I do then?

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean - but apturl isn't listed there either. But I know it's there since Firefox uses it!

Comment: @tuxtu Wierd... navigate to /usr/share/applications is there a file called apt-url there?

Comment: @handuel yes there is! It's actually called "AptURL.desktop".

Comment: That's odd, because if that file exists it should supposedly show up in the list. Try adding this line to the added associations section of ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:
application/x-deb=AptURL.desktop;

Comment: @handuel ok, when you type it without the "-" it works; at least it shows up in the "open-with" tab. But actually: apturl crashes when running a locally stored .deb then! But that maybe because I'm trying 13.04 here...

Comment: @Der_Techniker Yeah sorry, I misread what you said the filename was. I have amended my comment to say the correct filename. No idea about it crashing though.

Comment: @Der_Techniker I've got it, apt url is for opening remote .debs over the internet, I don't think it is designed for local .debs.